# How do i compare the the user response with actual answer that are stored- python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, dictionary

This for loop will get the user multiple reponse with values from radio button with values like 1, 3, 5, 2, 1 likewise....

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    resp_i = form.getvalue('opt_%d' %i, '0')
    resp[i] = resp_i
    print resp[i] 

output of this loop: 3 4 1 2 1 0 0 0 0
```

This code contains the actual answer which are stored in database with values like 1,2, 3 ,5, 2 likewise.......row[0] contains question id and row[1] contains the answer

```
for row in prsnobj.result:
    ansdb = {row[0] : row[1]}
    print ansdb

output:  {1L: 3L} {2L: 4L} {3L: 2L} {4L: 2L} {5L: 2L}
```

Now my question is I want to compare the user response with the actual answer that are stored in database.? hoe do i do that ?

The code which i tried......and its not feasible

```
res1= int(form.getvalue('opt_1', '0'))
res2 = int(form.getvalue('opt_2', '0'))
res3 = int(form.getvalue('opt_3', '0'))
res4 = int(form.getvalue('opt_4', '0'))
res5 = int(form.getvalue('opt_5', '0'))

actual_ans_dict = {}
count = 0
b = []
for data in prsnobj.result:
    actual_ans_dict[data[0]] = data[1]

if res1 == actual_ans_dict[1]:
    count += 1
if res2 == actual_ans_dict[2]:
    count += 1
if res3 == actual_ans_dict[3]:
    count += 1
if res4 == actual_ans_dict[4]:
    count += 1
if res5 == actual_ans_dict[5]:
    count += 1

if count:
    b.append(count)

if len(b)==0:
    print "Fail"

else:
   for each in b:
       print "<b>Score: ", each
```

Comment: what are the row[0] id's like? If they were simply numbered(1,2,3,4) to match the question numbers this would be easy

Comment: row[0] are simply numbers like 1,2,3,4,5......

Comment: What are the actual answers that are stored in the database?

Comment: Anyone who dislikes this post, please say why you disliked this post,that way the questioner would know what the problems is with his inquiry.

Comment: actual answer are stored in number like the above 2nd for loop output  {1L: 3L} means 1st id has 3rd options as answer

Comment: @Andy I'd guess because there appears to be no attempt by the asker to solve the problem for themselves, just asking for someone to do it.

Comment: I tried, but it was the other way...that solution was not feasible

Comment: It pays to show what you've tried, and you are less likely to be voted down..

Comment: @Totem: Updated..this was what i have tried

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: code runs completely fine....but what, if tomorrow one more question is added....the code i tried is completely static....i want dynamic

Comment: well, going by my answer below(and steve p's too I think), if a new answer is added to ansdb and a new response appended to resp, then all should work as before.

Comment: why don't you just add another question to ansdb and find out??

Comment: Ok ok, so now I know that resp is in fact a dict! You didn't mention that at all. I mentioned this in a comment on my answer. But that's why my code didn't work..

Comment: yes my resp is an dict........but i am not getting to why its giving keyerror:0

Comment: Can Anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you actually have a `dict` of questions to answers,

```
for index, answer in enumerate(xrange(len(resp))):
    if answer == ansbd[index + 1]:
        print "Correct"
    else:
        print "Incorrect!"
```

Here's the documentation for [Enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).  If I understood your question correctly.  The slots of list `resp` correspond to the questions numbers, aka keys in your `dict`, `ansbd`.  Hence we iterate through the `list` and for each entry, see if that mataches up to the coorespond answer in `ansbd`.

Comment: That means that the key is not in the map.  This will work if `1,2,...` are stored as keys in the map.

Comment: @user3003685 Prints out the keys in the map to see exactly what they are.  `for key in yourDict.keys(): print key`.  If they're not `1,2,3,...` as you said in your comment, this is why this method does not work.

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5 are the eys in my map..i checked that

Comment: @user3003685 Are you sure they're not strings?  If so, this won't work, and you'll have to do `str(index+1)`.  If not, I assure you that this will work if the length of `resp`, n, matches up to the number of questions [1,n].

Comment: yes they are not string...I have an column in database name QId..which is auto increment...and thus its an integer

Comment: @user3003685 This piece of code isn't rocket science.  If resp is length 4, it looks up keys 1,2,3,4 in the dict and compare their values to the response.  It has to work,as the other poster's update shows.  Something is not the way you think it is...

Comment: post your entire code once and for all, including it's output

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, len(resp)+1):     # assuming like you said, your question id's and answers are both integers
    if  resp[i] == ansdb[i]: # this assumes your question id's start at 1
        print "Right!" 
    else:
        print "Wrong.."

if resp = {1: 2, 2: 9, 3: 2, 4: 8, 5: 3, 6: 5}
and ansdb = {1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 3, 6: 5}

result is:

right
wrong
wrong
right
right
right

which it should be
```

Comment: this also assumes resp is a list. The question needs a lot of clarification

Comment: @Totem It obviously works, thanks for showing him, though. Something is not what OP says/thinks it is...

Comment: ok, well, if resp is a dict and ansdb is a dict.. and both use integers representing the question numbers as keys, and the answers as values, then this works...